# twisted task.LoopingCall messes callbacks when they are defined in loop

Tags: python, twisted

When there are some LoopingCall task defined in loop, twisted messes callbacks and always executes last one defined

sample code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from pprint import pprint

for s in [1,2]:
  task.LoopingCall(lambda: pprint(s)).start(1)

reactor.run()
```

response: `1 2 2 2 2 2`

code without loop that works:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from pprint import pprint

task.LoopingCall(lambda: pprint(1)).start(1)
task.LoopingCall(lambda: pprint(2)).start(1)

reactor.run()
```

correct response: `1 2 1 2 1 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of how scopes work in Python.

Forget about Twisted for a moment and just consider this example:

```
x = 1
f1 = lambda: x
x = 2
f2 = lambda: x
print f1()
print f2()
```

You might expect the result to be:

```
1
2
```

However, instead, it is:

```
2
2
```

The `f1` and `f2` functions both "close over" the same variable: `x`.  The variable can only refer to one object at a time, and after `x = 2`, it refers to `2` - not `1`.